# Chrome extension : access local storage more than once in content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know how to access localstorage in content script, but only one time. I access it via sendRequest, but when I try to use this method in an event function, the jvascript file doesn't even load.
Is it possible to access to the options many times, like whenever the onclick event is fired ?
I looked on the google code website and found something to create a connection between content script and background using chrome.extension.connect(). Do i need to use that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use `sendRequest` as many times as you can, but if you want to do it in another way you can open a [**long-lived channel**](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#connect) (or what I call, "message tunnel") between content script and background page to communicate.

**In your *content script***, you can use
`var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "myChannel"});`
to open up a channel.

Then you can use
`port.postMessage({message: "This is a message."});`
to send a new message to the `background page`.

`port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) { })` listens to a new message.

**In your *background page***,

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if(port=="myChannel"){
            console.log(msg+" from port "+port)        //Gives you the message
        }
    })
})
```

listens to a new message in a specific port.